# How to handle char and string in variable?

Tags: c++, struct, c++14

I have e.g. `struct`(structure) in C/C++ something like,

```cpp
struct _Token
{
    _DataTypes Type;
    std::string Value;
};
```

in C++ 14

But I want I want Value would be `(std::string || char): Value;`, how can I done that without `union` or things like that?

Comment: `std::variant`? Also [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: I haven't heard about it before, but `std::variant` looks useful.

Comment: I would just stick with `std::string Value` only. A char is a string of length 1. And with small string optimization NO memory is dynamically allocated for the string.

Comment: @display_name Could be useful, but handling variants is more complicated too. Look at the [visit part in the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: @OP "C/C++" does not exist these are two different languages. With C++ having a (mostly) backward compatible part with "C". (And yes sadly many developers mix the two and make a horrible mess)

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Token`, `_DataTypes`) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.